# How to make custom uibutton darker when pressed in cg?

Tags: ios, button, uibutton, rgb, uicolor

i need to make my custom buttom which is made in cg to be darker when user pressed it, just like original uibutton highlighted state. I came up with making alpha 50% but then background view is visible and i don't want that. Here is my code for that:

```
    func unhighlightButton(){
    self.color = someColor
    self.setNeedsDisplay()

}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet{
        if isHighlighted == true{
            self.gradientColor = someColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.perform(#selector(unhighlightButton), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be just set another color? (more darker than initial) and `self.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: i though about this one but perfect solution would be some func that changing color to be darker and the same color at the same time or something like this

Comment: how you wanna make color darker without changing color?